# Automated processing of an Email in C#

Tags: c#, outlook-2003

Similar question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56722/automated-processing-of-an-email-in-java) but for a Microsoft Environment.

Email --> Exchange Server -->[something]

For the [something] I was using Outlook 2003 & C# but it *feels* messy (A program is trying to access outlook, this could be a virus etc)

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application objOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpace objNS = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI");
objNS.Logon("MAPIProfile", "MAPIPassword", false, true);
```

Is this the best way to do it?  Is there a better way of retrieving and processing emails in a Microsoft environment???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/NetPopMimeClient.aspx) library provides you basic support for the POP3 protocol and MIME, you can use it to check specified mailboxes and retrieve emails and attachments, you can tweak it to your needs.

Here is [another library](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/imaplibrary.aspx), this one is for the IMAP protocol, it's very basic but also allows you to fetch complete messages, including attachments...

Answer (score 1):

I've been happy with the [Rebex components](http://www.rebex.net/mail.net/) which provide IMAP access.  Of course you need to ensure your Exchange administrators will open an IMAP port on your Exchange servers.

Comment: You could get along without the IMAP protocol as Rebex now offers a free beta of [Exchange Web Services wrapper](http://labs.rebex.net/ExchangeWebServices/) which easily integrates with Rebex Secure Mail (disclaimer - I work for the company).

Answer (score 1):

Using IMAP is a way to go. You can use [Mail.dll IMAP component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/):

```
using(Imap imap = new Imap())
{
    imap.Connect("imap.company.com");
    imap.UseBestLogin("user", "password");

    imap.SelectInbox();
    List<long> uids = imap.Search(Flag.Unseen);
    foreach (long uid in uids)
    {
          var eml = imap.GetMessageByUID(uid);
          IMail message = new MailBuilder()
                    .CreateFromEml(eml);

          Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
          Console.WriteLine(message.Text); 
    }
    imap.Close(true);
}
```

You can download it here: [Mail.dll email component](http://www.lesnikowski.com/mail/).

Answer (score -1):

I am trying http://csharpopensource.com/openpopdotnet.aspx, it have been recently updated and it is not bad. It lack good documentation but it also work with gmail/ssl.